# How to set dynamic row height in ng-grid?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have problem with ng - grid
in cellTemplate i hane ng-repeat :`<div ng-repeat="address in row.entity.addresses>"
but height of row is constant and some of addresses i can't see`

what i need to do?

[Angular ng-grid row height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094723/angular-ng-grid-row-height)

this solution removes cell's border

Comment: You can't do dynamic row heights with ng-grid. This was answered dozens of times before. Look at something like trNgGrid which uses a html table instead of divs: http://moonstorm.github.io/trNgGrid

Comment: Seems like github.io is down at the moment. Try again later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a commonly requested feature for ng-grid, but currently there aren't any plans to add it. [[0]](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/1230)

This is because table virtualization is a big feature for ng-grid that's important to a lot of people, and they haven't written/figured out logic to quickly estimate the total height of all rows while only rendering, for example, 30 of them.

At this time your options are to look at other grid/table libraries, or to figure out another UX that you're okay with (e.g. maybe only render the first 60 characters and provide the rest in a tooltip when the user hovers/taps the cell)

Comment: You are right with your answer, but I was always asking me why it is important to virtualize/fake a table when you want to display table data and have a table rendering engine at hand in your browser. Don't get me wrong, I'm using ng-grid by myself but I never understood why they have to do this so complicated and bug prone. Any clues?

Comment: Virtualization can be very helpful if you have very large tables. The DOM becomes very slow on most computers if you have 100,000 rows. For one thing, styling will be calculated for rows that may never even be looked at. Almost every benefit that you can find for lazy-loading in general (as in, in other fields, such as databases), can be applied to table virtualization.

Comment: Ok, that's reasonable. I have never worked with such large tables. Thanks for the explanation.