# Dynamically increase ng-grid row height depending on content without additional plugins and jquery

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-grid, row-height

This question was already asked here [Angular ng-grid row height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094723/angular-ng-grid-row-height)

but that are all not satisfy my requirement if we use CSS to fix problem it affect page responsiveness and ng-grid's header functionalities like sort,etc
 .

```
.ngCell  {
  display : table-cell;
  height: auto !important;
  overflow:visible;
  position: static;
}

.ngRow {
  display : table-row;
  height: auto !important;
  position: static;
}

.ngCellText{
  height: auto !important;
  white-space: normal;
  overflow:visible;
}
```

there is any solution for this without affecting page responsiveness and have to solve by pure java script / angularjs/css

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented an easy solution to dynamically change the table's height strictly based on the visible rows. I am using Ui-Grid-Unstable v3.0

My HTML looks like:

```
<div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-grouping ui-grid-exporter class="grid"></div>
```

In your controller add:

```
$scope.$watch('gridApi.core.getVisibleRows().length', function() {
    if ($scope.gridApi) {
        $scope.gridApi.core.refresh();
        var row_height = 30;
        var header_height = 31;
        var height = row_height * $scope.gridApi.core.getVisibleRows().length + header_height;
        $('.grid').height(height);
        $scope.gridApi.grid.handleWindowResize();
    }
});
```

And to turn off scrolling add the following line where gridOptions is initialized:

```
enableVerticalScrollbar : uiGridConstants.scrollbars.NEVER,
```

Make sure uiGridConstants is passed into your controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller('mainController', function($scope, uiGridConstants) { ...
```

Hope this helps!